# Total time of flight between two time zones?

Tags: java, timezone, java-8, java-time

If we leave Frankfurt at 14:05 and arrives in Los Angeles at 16:40. How long is the flight?

I tried the below :

```
ZoneId frank = ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin");
ZoneId los = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles");

LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2015, 02, 20, 14, 05);
LocalDateTime dateTime2 = LocalDateTime.of(2015, 02, 20, 16, 40);

ZonedDateTime berlinDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(dateTime, frank);
ZonedDateTime losDateTime2 = ZonedDateTime.of(dateTime2, los);

int offsetInSeconds = berlinDateTime.getOffset().getTotalSeconds();
int offsetInSeconds2 = losDateTime2.getOffset().getTotalSeconds();

Duration duration = Duration.ofSeconds(offsetInSeconds - offsetInSeconds2);
System.out.println(duration);
```

But I am not able to get the successful answer which is about 11hrs and 30min. Will some one please help me to figure out the problem above. Thanks you :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`getOffset` is the wrong method.  That gets the UTC offset for that zone at that point in time.  It doesn't help determine the actual time of day.

One way is to explicitly get the `Instant` represented by each value, using `toInstant`.  Then use `Duration.between` to calculate the amount of time elapsed.

```
Instant departingInstant = berlinDateTime.toInstant();
Instant arrivingInstant = losDateTime2.toInstant();
Duration duration = Duration.between(departingInstant, arrivingInstant);
```

Alternatively, since `Duration.between` works on `Temporal` objects, and both `Instant` and `ZonedDateTime` implement `Temporal`, you can just call `Duration.between` directly on the `ZonedDateTime` objects:

```
Duration duration = Duration.between(berlinDateTime, losDateTime2);
```

And lastly, there are shortcuts like the one atao mentioned that are fine if you want to get directly at a unit of measure such as total seconds.  Any of these are acceptable.

Comment: thank you @matt for the great explanation and will  keep in mind those things in the future \,,/

Answer (score 6):

Replace:

```
int offsetInSeconds = berlinDateTime.getOffset().getTotalSeconds();
int offsetInSeconds2 = losDateTime2.getOffset().getTotalSeconds();

Duration duration = Duration.ofSeconds(offsetInSeconds - offsetInSeconds2);
```

with:

```
long seconds = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(berlinDateTime, losDateTime2);
Duration duration = Duration.ofSeconds(seconds);
```

EDIT

I like the shorter (and shortest) answer given by Matt Johnson:

```
Duration duration = Duration.between(berlinDateTime, losDateTime2);
```

Comment: No need for you to be worrying about total seconds, no need to call `getTotalSeconds`.  Let `Duration` do that work for you. See the other Answer by Johnson for an example.